# Code Igniter: allowing apostrophe in URI's while depending on Query Bindings for safety

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri, apostrophe

I've been figuring out how to let apostrophe's cross URI's.

I'm building a site that allows users to "create photo albums". I have a link that when clicked, it will load and display all the contents of a certain album. I'm using codeigniter so this page is called this way:

```
http://www.fourthdraft.com/index.php/admin/manageAlbumContents/dan's/91
```

admin = controller
managealbums = function
dan's (album name) = variable

As you know, codeigniter does not allow apostrophe(') in uri's. My problems are:

1. If I htmlspecialchars/htmlentities
   the album name it becomes &#xx;
   Those new characters also not
   allowed
2. If I url encode it becomes %xx. percent is allowed but codeigniter
   urldecodes it before processing so
   it just reverts back to apostrophe
3. I've tried making my own preg_replace ( ' => '~apos~' ) but i
   just find it inefficient, too much
   lines to run and tedious since I
   have an 80% done website and the
   strings I have to replace are
   everywhere.
4. I've also considered using base64_encode. It takes more space
   but it does the job. Then again, the
   encoded version contains '=' which
   is also disallowed

As much as possible I do not want to just add apostrophe in the allowed characters list in codeigniter's config file. I believe they don't have it there for a reason. At the same time, I'm running out of options. 
The reason for wanting to allow apostrophe's is because in this context, it's bound to be used. For example, what if someone decided to put 'dan's birthday party' as an album name? It's bound to happen. and i'm pretty sure my users would complain. Even if I manage to convince them otherwise, what will i replace that with? dan_s birthday party? looks wrong. Also, if facebook can do it I should too. At the very least, if facebook did it, then that means there's a way.

If you guys have any suggestions, fire away. Otherwise I'm wondering if it's ok (and safe) to just allow apostrophe in the allowed URI characters. I know it's VERY dangerous for mysql which i use a lot but I just remembered codeigniter's query binding variables automatically escapes characters. I'm wondering if that would suffice and keep me safe.

Otherwise, please please please give me a good idea. I'm drained out

Comment: From what you say about MySQL I'm guessing you take the URI segment ant do a lookup in the database. Why not have a look at the URL for your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366821/code-igniter-allowing-apostrophe-in-uris-while-depending-on-query-bindings-for I assume that the integer is the ID of the question which is actually used for the DB lookup. Or you could have two fields in you DB one with the real name and one with a simplified URL friendly name

Comment: thanks, this is the most useful. WHY HAVE I NOT THOUGHT OF THIS BEFORE

Answer (score 0):

I like to believe that the days of `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE x={$_GET['val']}")` are over. That being said, it's OK with any decent database library as long as you use parameter binding. So go ahead and use `urlencode`.